# basic javascript getElementById clarification

Tags: javascript

I had to do a simple calculator using HTML and JS and since I've never programmed on JS I have a question in order to get the logic right. Here is the code:

I have a function which has to write on the screen of my calculator;

```
function writeToScreen(a) {
    var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
    switch (a.value) {
    case '+': {
        if (firstOperation) {
            lastOperation = '+';
            firstNumber = elem.value;
            elem.value = "";
            firstOperation = 0;
        } else {
            lastOperation = '+';
            firstNumber += elem.value;
        }
    }
        break;

    case '-': {
        if (firstOperation) {
            lastOperation = '-';
            firstNumber = elem.value;
            elem.value = "";
            firstOperation = 0;
        } else {
            lastOperation = '-';
            firstNumber -= elem.value;
        }
    }
        break;

    case '*': {
        if (firstOperation) {
            lastOperation = '*';
            firstNumber = elem.value;
            elem.value = "";
            firstOperation = 0;
        } else {
            lastOperation = '*';
            firstNumber *= elem.value;
        }
    }
        break;

    case '/': {
        if (firstOperation) {
            lastOperation = '/';
            firstNumber = elem.value;
            elem.value = "";
            firstOperation = 0;
        } else {
            lastOperation = '/';
            firstNumber /= elem.value;
        }
    }
        break;
    case '=': {
        if (firstOperation) {

        } else {
            switch (lastOperation) {
            case '+': {
                elem.value = (firstNumber + elem.value);
            }
                break;
            case '-': {
                elem.value = firstNumber - elem.value;
            }
                break;
            case '/': {
                elem.value = firstNumber / elem.value;
            }
                break;
            case '*': {
                elem.value = firstNumber * elem.value;
            }
                break;

            default: {

            }
                break;
            }

            firstOperation = 1;
            lastOperation = '';
        }
    }
        break;

    case 'C': {
        elem.value = "";
    }
        break;
    case '1': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '2': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '3': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '4': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '5': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '6': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '7': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '8': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '9': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    case '0': {
        elem.value += a.value;
    }
        break;
    default: {

    }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the screen of my calculator:

```
<td colspan=3 align="center"><input id="screen" type=text disabled></input></td>
```

and here is one button of my calc:

```
<td align="center"><button type="button" onclick="writeToScreen(this)" value=4>4</button></td>
```

Now to the question and to check whether my logic is right. Basically when I press on the button, the function writeToScreen is called, giving as parameter (this) the value 4 for the current button. The number 4 is now displayed in the screen of my calculator, but I don't see where the displaying is coming from. Is it from the getElementById('screen'). Is this function checking if 'screen' id is of input type and then displaying it? Where exactly is the displaying happening?

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see more of the `writeToScreen` function

Comment: function writeToScreen(a) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('screen');
  switch (a.value) {
  case '+': {
   if (firstOperation) {
    lastOperation = '+';
    firstNumber = elem.value;
    elem.value = "";
    firstOperation = 0;
   } else {
    lastOperation = '+';
    firstNumber += elem.value;
   }
  }
   break;

Comment: You can edit your post and put the code in there where it won't be truncated :)

Comment: `this` is the element clicked. You pass it to the function, so now that element is referenced by the `a` parameter. When you do `a.value`, get fetches the current value of the element, which is `4` for that button. The `elem` variable refers to the `screen` input. You assign to its `.value` property in order to update the display. So every `elem.value = "...whatever..."` is updating the value of the `screen` element, and therefore its display.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but my question is where the displaying of the actual number is coming from. I mean when i press 4, I see 4 on the screen of the calc, where is the line that makes the display? Something like System.out.print("4"); in JAVA :) does getElementsById('screen'); does it ? since screen is of type input?

Comment: Setting the `value` property of the element will update the display.

Comment: @user3240544: I accidentally hit enter, which submitted my previous comment prematurely. *(That shouldn't happen for `textarea` elements!!!)* I added more detail.

Comment: ...here's a simpler example. http://jsfiddle.net/340d7s9c/ So it has nothing to do with `getElementById()`. That's just a method for fetching an element from the DOM. Updating the `.value` of an input element will update its display. Note that most elements do not have a `.value`. Most other ones, like a `<div>` will have its content updated using `.appendChild()` or `.textContent` or other properties and methods.

Comment: @squint: consider writing up your comments as an answer so it can be accepted!

Comment: @rossipedia: I'll give it very long and thoughtful consideration, and then will probably just decide to skip it.

Answer (score 2):

The line `var elem = document.getElementById('screen')` gets the element with `id` attribute set to `screen`, which in this case is an `input` element. Form elements (in which the `input` elements belong to) has an property called `value` which, as the name suggests, is the value of the element. This property can be accessed by doing `formElement.value`. This property is also writeable, which means that you can set its value programatically by doing `formElement.value = theValue`.

In your case, your `elem` variable is an input element, so you can get or set its value using the methods described above. So the lines which displays the value in your `screen` element are those lines where you do `elem.value += ...` or `elem.value = ""` (`...` here means any value).

Answer (score 1):

[Dom Event Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)
[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

```
<!-- when "click" event is triggered on this button/element, call writeToScreen -->
<!-- with "this", the button element itself, as it's first argument -->
<button type="button" onclick="writeToScreen(this)" value=4>
```

And the function...

```
// define a function, store the first arg as "a"
function writeToScreen(a) {

    // define a local variable named "elem"
    // look for the element you want to manipulate by calling
    // "getElementById" of "document" with a string "screen" as it's only argument
    var elem = document.getElementById('screen');

    // switch "value" of the clicked button element, which "a" is referring to
    switch (a.value) {
      ...
      case '4': { // if the button being clicked has a value === "4"
        elem.value += a.value; // set the value of "elem"(id="screen") += a.value
```

....Button "4" clicked, call writeToScreen, then make screen's value += 4, seems wrong LOL